# In Justice League: Doom, Why Didn't Superman gain the same illness as in All-Star Superman?

Tags: dc, superman, justice-league-doom

In the new movie Justice league: Doom, it shows Superman

> Flying into the sun (or well into the corona) to stop a weapon from causing a cataclysmic event.

Why didn't this have the same effect as when

> Superman flew too close to the sun in All Star Superman (which wasn't even as close in this new film)?

Why Didn't Superman gain the same illness as in All-Star Superman?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The All-Star Superman comic, which was made into an animated film by 'DC Original Animated Movies' that was set in a different continuity, whereas Justice League Doom, which was inspired by the justice league comic 'Tower of Babel' written by Mark Weid, which was set in the current DC continuity so the Supermans are not the same, which is why their weaknesses to high exposure to a yellow sun are different.

Comment: All Star Superman is a non-canon amalgam of all of DC's Supermen. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12327/2765

The Justice League Doom Superman is not the same character.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response, but in All-Star Superman, Lex had infected superman. When the illness starts, Supes is fighting a monster being controlled remotely by Lex, and when it is destroyed, Supes is infected with the condition that causes him to metabolize sunlight at a much higher rate.